# How many types of InputFormat is there in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to `Hadoop` and wondering how many types of `InputFormat` are there in `Hadoop` such as `TextInputFormat`? Is there a certain `InputFormat` that I can use to read files via http requests to remote data servers?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

There are many `classes` implementing [InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html)

```
CombineFileInputFormat, CombineSequenceFileInputFormat, 
CombineTextInputFormat, CompositeInputFormat, DBInputFormat,
FileInputFormat, FixedLengthInputFormat, KeyValueTextInputFormat, 
MultiFileInputFormat, NLineInputFormat, Parser.Node, 
SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat, SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat, 
SequenceFileInputFilter, SequenceFileInputFormat, TextInputFormat
```

Have a look at this [article](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/class-use/InputFormat.html) on when to use which type of `Inputformat`.

Out of these, most frequently used `formats` are:

- `FileInputFormat` : Base class for all file-based InputFormats
- `KeyValueTextInputFormat` : An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines. Either line feed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line. Each line is divided into key and value parts by a separator byte. If no such a byte exists, the key will be the entire line and value will be empty.
- `TextInputFormat` : An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines. Either linefeed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line. Keys are the position in the file, and values are the line of text..
- `NLineInputFormat` : NLineInputFormat which splits N lines of input as one split. In many "pleasantly" parallel applications, each process/mapper processes the same input file (s), but with computations are controlled by different parameters.
- `SequenceFileInputFormat` : An InputFormat for SequenceFiles.

Regarding second query, get the files from remote `servers` first and use appropriate `InputFileFormat` depending on contents in file. `Hadoop` works best for data locality.

Comment: What about the second question? Is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 4):

Your first question - how many types of InputFormat are there in Hadoop such as TextInputFormat?

1. `TextInputFormat` - each line will be treated as value
2. `KeyValueTextInputFormat` - First value before delimiter is key and rest is value
3. `FixedLengthInputFormat` - Each fixed length value is considered to be value
4. `NLineInputFormat` - N number of lines is considered one value/record
5. `SequenceFileInputFormat` - For binary

Also there is `DBInputFormat` to read from databases

You second question - there is no input format to read files via http requests.